# Datetime format Issue: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I want to format the input string into **MM/dd/yyyy  hh:mm:ss** format in C#.
The input string is in format `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`
For example :`"04/30/2013 23:00"`

I tried `Convert.ToDateTime()` function, but it considers 4 as date and 3 as month which is not what I want. Actually month is 04 and date is 03.

I tried `DateTime.ParseExact()` function also, But getting Exception.

I am getting error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Can you post the actual source code that you have trouble with?

Comment: Well how did you try `ParseExact` ? i guess you missed something for the format passed simple guess it would be `HH` instead of `hh` since you have 24 hr format

Comment: r u use datetime picker ?

Comment: @PranayRana I'm wondering which answer take the first upvote :) Or they ever will? :)

Comment: @SonerGönül - whatever but point is OP must accept correct answer...

Comment: Actually I was trying to use the format MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.But my input string was not containing ss part.That was the reason of error.Anyway,thanks every one. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your date time string doesn't contains any seconds. You need to reflect that in your format (remove the `:ss`).
Also, you need to specify `H` instead of `h` if you are using 24 hour times:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("04/30/2013 23:00", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

See here for more information:

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: `str = "6"; dtm = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` is failing for me. Any idea?

Comment: @Si8 It's because "d" is a standard format string (short date). You can use "%d" instead. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method.

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.**

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("04/30/2013 23:00", 
                                    "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", 
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/Q93nC3).

`hh` is for 12-hour clock from 01 to 12, `HH` is for 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.

For more information, check [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
string strTime = "04/30/2013 23:00";
DateTime dtTime;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(strTime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm",  
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
   System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dtTime))
 {
    Console.WriteLine(dtTime);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be the problem if your string is 6/15/2019. DateTime Parse expects it to be 06/15/2019.

So first split it by slash

```
var dateParts = "6/15/2019"
var month = dateParts[0].PadLeft(2, '0');
var day = dateParts[1].PadLeft(2, '0');
var year = dateParts[2] 


var properFormat = month + "/" +day +"/" + year;
```

Now you can use DateTime.Parse(properFormat, "MM/dd/yyyy"). It is very strange but this is only thing working for me.

Answer (score 1):

change the culture and try out like this might work for you

```
string[] formats= { "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" }
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("04/30/2013 23:00", 
     formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Check for details : [DateTime.ParseExact Method (String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact([YourDate], "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",  
                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note the use of HH (24-hour clock) rather than hh (12-hour clock), and the use of InvariantCulture because some cultures use separators other than slash.

For example, if the culture is de-DE, the format "dd/MM/yyyy" would expect period as a separator (31.01.2011).

Answer (score 0):

**Below code worked for me:**

```
string _stDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-12)).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
String format ="MM/dd/yyyy";
IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR", true);
DateTime _Startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(_stDate, format, culture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this type format (get formatted data from sql server)

---

FORMAT(convert(datetime,'16/04/2018 10:52:20',103),'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'en-us')

---

CONVERT(VARCHAR,convert(datetime,'16/04/2018 10:52:20',103), 120)

Answer (score 0):

I have created an extension method that I use everytime

```
    public static DateTime? ToDateTime(this string dateTime)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTime))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(dateTime, new string[] { "MMM dd, yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "d/M/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "d-M-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", "yyyy-MM-dd" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).DateTime;
    }
```

I have added multiple formats that I encounter in an array and I reuse this method every time, the above method works for the following examples of date:

- May 23, 2022
- 5-08-2023
- 05-08-2023
- 5/08/2023
- 05/08/2023
- 2023-02-01
- 2023-02-01T12:23:99Z

additionally in c# the answer of [@Manjay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56616280/12417530) can also be tried as follows :

```
    char formatChar = '-';
    if (dateTime.Contains('-'))
    {
        formatChar = '-';
    }

    if (dateTime.Contains('/'))
    {
        formatChar = '/';
    }

    string[] parts = dateTime.Split(formatChar);
    var month = parts[0].PadLeft(2, '0');
    var day = parts[1].PadLeft(2, '0');
    var year = parts[2];
    string properFormattedDate = $"{month}{formatChar}{day}{formatChar}{year}";

    return DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(properFormattedDate, new string[] { "MMM dd, yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", "yyyy-MM-dd" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).DateTime;
```