# Error “String was not recognized as a valid DateTime”

Tags: c#

I have these 2 string values:

- `Test1 = "2020-01-29T00:00:00Z"`
- `Test2 = "29/01/2020 00:00:00"`

and I am doing this comparison:

```
(DateTime.ParseExact(Test2.ToString(), "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'00':'00':'00'Z'") != (DateTime.ParseExact(Test1["ProjectDateSinged"].ToString(), "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'00':'00':'00'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString()))
```

but this will raise the following exception:

> Error “String was not recognized as a valid DateTime”

Could anyone find what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Try to use `MM` instead of `M` for month

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datetime format Issue: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014101/datetime-format-issue-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i tried this but still i will get the same error

Comment: @testtest please have a look at my answer

Comment: I think perhaps there should be a canonical duplicate close question target for these "Why doesn't my DateTime.ParseExact parse this string" when the formats doesn't match *exactly*.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding my comment into answer, you should update your format string a little bit. For `Test2` you should use `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format.

According to [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) `MM` is used for month number from `01` to `12`, `M` from `1` to `12`. You have `01` month number, so `MM` should be used.

There is also no AM/PM representation in your date, so `tt` is not needed as well

Them you'll be able to parse `Test2` into the date.

```cs
var Test2 = "29/01/2020 00:00:00";
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(Test2, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For the `Test1` you can use `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssK` (parse the date including time zone information) or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss'Z'` without time zone information.

To compare the dates you don't need to convert them back to string. You can simply get the date component using [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.8) property of `DateTime` struct. The code below returns `true`

```cs
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(Test1, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date ==
             DateTime.ParseExact(Test2, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date;
```

as well as this, by comparing two `DateTime` instances only

```cs
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(Test1, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ==
             DateTime.ParseExact(Test2, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: i tried replacing M with MM but i am still getting the same error

Comment: @testtest you should also remove `tt`, as it stated in the answer. Please, check it

Comment: ok thanks but i am not sure why does this `(DateTime.ParseExact(Test1["ProjectDateSinged"].ToString(), "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'00':'00':'00'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString())` will return the date as follow `29/01/2020 00:00:00"` ??

Comment: @testtest because you skip the time component during parsing using `'` quotes. To get the correct date you need `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss'Z'` (omit time zone) or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssK` (use timezone)

Comment: i mean the `(DateTime.ParseExact(Test1["ProjectDateSinged"].ToString(), "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'00':'00':'00'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString())` should return the string as follow `2020-01-29T00:00:00z` and not as `29/01/2020 00:00:00`.. is this correct?

Comment: @testtest it returns `1/29/2020 12:00:00 AM` (at my end a least). `z` is omitted during parsing. It isn't clear why do you need to convert the date to string back and compare. You can use `Date` property of date time to get a date component and compare it

Answer (score 1):

```
        string Test1 = "2020-01-29T00:00:00Z";

        string Test2 = "29/01/2020 00:00:00";


        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(Test1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

       MessageBox.Show("" + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00Z"));
```

Used this code then successfully work

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your examples, the formats looks below.. You can write a generalized method by specifying formats. something like below -

```
private static DateTime ParseDate(string providedDate)
{
    DateTime validDate;
    string[] formats = {  "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'" };
    var dateFormatIsValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(
        providedDate,
        formats,
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.None,
        out validDate);
    return dateFormatIsValid ? validDate : DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

And call this method to parse the string

```
 var test1 = ParseDate("2020-01-29T00:00:00Z");
 var test2 = ParseDate("29/01/2020 00:00:00");

 Console.WriteLine(test1 == test2); // result TRUE
```